# How can I add an additional column to the belongsToMany Association using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, many-to-many, associations

I am using Node, Express, Postgres and Sequelize

Hi I am using using Sequelize I am successful in creating the through table with the belongsToMany for my Postgres database. But I want to add an additional column to it but cant figure out how to do it and I have searched the web and found no answer.

I got these two tables:

1. Customers
2. Store Products

This here below is my Sequelize method of creating the third table using the `belongsToMany` association (many-to-many) and I will be calling the table order_list.

```
  customer.belongsToMany(storeProduct, { 
    through: 'order_list',
    unique: false,
    foreignKey: 'customers_cid',
    // How can I add this additional column quantity to it?
    quantity: { /// How do I add it?
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
  });

  storeProduct.belongsToMany(customer, { 
    through: 'order_list',
    unique: false,
    foreignKey: 'store_products_spid',
    // How can I add this additional column quantity to it?
    quantity: { /// How do I add it?
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
  });

  sequelize.sync({ alter: true });
```

So how can I successfully add the column I quantity with type of INTEGER to the this new order_list table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `OrderList` model explicitly with additional column and then use it in `belongsToMany` in the option `through`.
See [Advanced Many-To_many](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html) guide in the official documentation.

Example:

```js
const User_Profile = sequelize.define('User_Profile', {
  selfGranted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
}, { timestamps: false });
User.belongsToMany(Profile, { through: User_Profile });
Profile.belongsToMany(User, { through: User_Profile });
```